# Using unbiased estimator in Metropolis-Hasting Algorithm

Tags: probability, markov-chains, estimation, simulation

I am trying to estimate an unknown distribution say, $p(x)$, using MH-Algorithm.

Assume that there is a function $f(x) \propto p(x)$,

However, the exact $f(x)$ is also unknown, I can only compute its unbiased estimator say $\hat{f}(x)$, i.e., $E(\hat{f}(x))=E(f(x))$ for all $x$.

Is there any related theoretical results that can analyze the convergence rate or stability for such method?

Comment: "I am trying to estimate an unknown distribution say, ()"
do you mean you are trying to draw samples from $p$?

Comment: I guess sampling using MH will only be as good as your estimate of the density. Meaning that samples will be according to the density that you have estimated, $\hat f$, not $f$. What convergence rate or stability are you referring to? Since your samples will *never* be drawn from $f$ (only from $\hat f$)

Comment: Hi dmh, thanks for reply. The convergence rate is the total variation error between the target distribution p(x) and the one from MH.  
I thought that I can bound the error between f and its estimator, also I can bound the error between sample distribution and p(x), maybe there is a way to combine them together?

Comment: Since MH converges, then the sampling distribution can be as close as you want to  that of the estimated distribution. Why would bounding the estimation and MH error together be interesting?

Comment: Ah, nothing special, I am just thinking if everything can be put together in one inequality should be great lol

Comment: It kind of reminds me of the line of work in statistical learning  which explores the tradeoff between estimation error and optimization error. But in that case, lower estimation error can lead to more difficult optimization problems, so the optimization error increases. But in your case, I don't see a similar tradeoff, do you?

Comment: https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2007/file/0d3180d672e08b4c5312dcdafdf6ef36-Paper.pdf